# Displaying image according to cell image iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have tableViewCell having cell images defined in cellForRowAtIndexPath method like

```
switch (row) {

    case 0:

        rowImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"euro.png"];
        cell.imageView.image=rowImage;
        break;

    case 1:

        rowImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"us.png"];
        cell.imageView.image=rowImage;   
        break;
```

Now on next view whatever cell user selects i want to show corresponding image on that view which is normal xib file. The image should not cover whole xib file but a tiny place on it

How can i implement that.

Thanks

Comment: Make a UIImageView in the size and location you want, connect it as a IBOutlet, and set its `.image` property programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by creating an array which holds the image names in the same sequence as u have added in the table from 0th row to how much u have added in total. Now in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method pass ther row which is being selected to array's index, like this :

```
  NSString *imgName =[imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Now you have ur selected image name. You can now pass this name to the next viewcontroller in which u want to display the image. For that just create a method in the next viewcontroller class with string paramter. Pass this image name string to that method. Example,

```
NSString *localImgName = [getImageName imgName];
```

where getImageName is the method in the other view controller. Now u can use the obtained imageName in the localImgName variable and use that to set an image to the UIImageView.
Hope this helps.  I have explained in a programmatic way..

Answer (score 1):

Do this with the help of delegate.
In this method,

```
switch (row) {

    case 0:

        appDelegate.rowID = 0;
        rowImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"euro.png"];
        cell.imageView.image=rowImage;
        break;

    case 1:

        appDelegate.rowID = 1;
        rowImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"us.png"];
        cell.imageView.image=rowImage;   
        break;
```

rowID is an int in yourAppDelegate file.

```
  //inYourNextViewController.m file
  - (void)viewDidLoad {
           [super viewDidLoad];

           appDelegate = (yourAppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
           switch(appDelegate.rowID)
           {
                   case 0:
                   yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image1];
                   break;

                   case 1:
                   yourImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:image2];
                   break;
           }

   }
```